DefaultBatchConfigurer in spring boot 3
How to set datasource in defaultBatchConfigurer in spring boot 3.
Public class BatchConfigurer extends DefaultBatchConfigurarion{

@Autowired
public void setDataSource(Datasource dataSource){

}
}
Getting error defaultBatchConfigurer cannot be resolved to a type when upgrading from spring boot 2.7 to 3.0
I tried changing the class name to defaultBatchConfiguration but am unable to override setDataSource as there is no such method in it.

BatchConfigurer was removed in Spring Batch 5. There is no need to define one in spring Boot 3. All you need is define your job bean in the application context and spring boot will run it for you.
If you want to customize the data source, you can either:

use @BatchDataSource on the datasource you want to use for Spring Batch,
or extend DefaultBatchConfiguration and override getDataSource()
or use @EnableBatchProcessing(dataSource = "dataSourceBeanName")


upgrading from spring boot 2.7 to 3.0

Please check the migration guide for more details about this: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide#spring-batch-changes
